# Scan text document to PDF with OCR

Tags: pdf, ocr, scanning

I need to scan text documents to PDFs.

I found that my Canon scanner's utility and VueScan's OCR works horrible. ABBYY Fine Reader works good enough, but I would like to look at other alternatives.

I need an alternative to compare OCR and picture quality and scan+OCR speed and select the best solution.

Operating system Windows or Linux. Budget - unlimited.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to try out other commercial solutions, you can check out the [LEADTOOLS OCR SDK](http://www.leadtools.com) which also has the ability to OCR and create document based PDFs (among most other document formats). There is a free 60-day evaluation so you can evaluate the speed and accuracy using your images.

Disclaimer: I am an employee of this company.

Comment: So I think you can compare OCR in your solution against ABBYY and tell us  better than anybody :) Who is best in OCR-ing in the world?

Comment: LEADTOOLS of course! But I may be a bit biased. On a serious note, we have been in business for over 25 years & we've seen customers come to us with similar questions after facing difficulties with other vendors.

OCR varies greatly depending on the input image's quality. Included in the SDK is a huge library of image processing & document cleanup functions that can process the image prior to going through OCR to increase accuracy & speed.

We'd love to help you with evaluating the entire process in addition to OCR to come up with a best solution for the images you are generating.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many of them, and ABBYY has the most accurate OCR, and very fixable in terms of the supported formats (it support djvu, what is unique as I know), and many other commercial software are actually using ABBYY dll libraries for OCR, for example FoxitReader (well, this was couple years ago, not sure if that is the case now).

Comment: ABBYY is using its own OCR library? I suppose there should be not many  OCR API in the world - what are the main competitors?